# Angular Javascript object with arrays, looping through and getting length of each array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, lodash

I'm trying to create a dataset from an API backend I've set up in my project. I've already managed to group my api call on the date but now I need to check the length of each date array that is created by lodash.

How would I do this because every attempt I've tried so far has failed. The image I've included shows the console.log after I have grouped my result, it also shows the amount of entries in each array which is exactly what I want to retrieve.

Current code, I removed my attempt at solving this problem because I would only get back undefined results.

```js
        ngOnInit() {
        this._estimateService.getEstimates()
            .subscribe(estimateData => {
                const groupedEstimateData = groupBy(estimateData, 'estimate_date');
                console.log(groupedEstimateData);
            });
        }
```

Example of desired result:

```
2019-12-09, 47
2019-12-10, 6
etc
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: May you also post what you actually get from `estimateData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you mean by "checking the length".
Here is an example of your desired console.log output

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._estimateService.getEstimates()
            .subscribe(estimateData => {
                const groupedEstimateData = groupBy(estimateData, 'estimate_date');
                Object.entries(groupedEstimatesData).map(([date, estimatedData]) => {
                    // do what you want there with each line
                    console.log(date, estimatedData.length);
                });
            });
        }
```

You can have a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) methods.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the Object.entries and map method suggestions. Your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
const groupsWithCounts = Object.keys(groupedEstimateData).map(key => {
    [key]: groupedEstimateData[key],
    total: groupedEstimateData[key].length
})
```

Now `groupsWithCounts` will be an array of objects with this structure:

```
{
    2019-12-9: [item, item, item, ...], // the original items
    total: 47 // the total count of items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with :

```js
const dates = Object.keys(groupedEstimateData);

let output = {};

dates.forEach( date => output[date] = groupedEstimateData[date].length );
```

`Object.keys(groupedEstimateData)` will give you an array `["2019-12-09", "2019-12-10", etc]`

You then iterate this array to construct this output object :

```
{
    "2019-12-09" : 47,
    "2019-12-10" : 6,
    etc
}
```